# scheduler design in java which can schedule task on available machines

Tags: java

i have a requirement ,pla help me with this

Design and develop a scheduler which schedule task on available machines.

Machines can be of different configuration like

1. 2 core machine
2. 4 core machine
3. 8 GB RAM
4. 16 GB RAM
5. 500 GB DISK
6. 1000 GC disk space

Each machine will be combination of above 3 types(core, RAM and Disk)

Task may come with or without required configuration. 
like task1 can run on any machine
task 2 should run only on machine which has atleast 8 GB RAM
task 3 can run only on machine which has atleast 4 core and 8 GB RAM

Scheduler should schedule task based on task configuration.

Tasks should execute in a way they come to system. Time Priority can be overridden if there is no resource available to schedule particular task.
At any point of time, User should be able to find 
How many task are pending ?
How many task are pending which required RAM more than 8 GB etc?

pls help me withthis.

thanks in advance

Comment: Examples ? what did u try so far ? what OS running on target machines ? why java ... maybe shell scripting ?

Comment: actually its an interview question,and should be done in java...please help me with some limelight

Comment: can somebody help me with the algorithm and proper data structures

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example to create tasks and machines :

```
// class for tasks 
public class Task {
   private String name;
   private String command;

   public Task(String name, String command){
      this.name = name;
      this.command = command;
   }

   public void doTask(){
      System.out.println("running task " + this.name + " with command " + this.command);
   }
}

// class for machines
public class Machine {
   private int numOfCores;
   private int ramSizeGB;
   private int diskSpaceGB;
   private List<Task> tasks;

   public Machine(int numOfCores, int ramSizeGB, int diskSpaceGB){
      this.numOfCores = numOfCores;
      this.ramSizeGB = ramSizeGB;
      this.diskSpaceGB = diskSpaceGB;
      tasks = new ArrayList<Task>();
   }

   public void addTask(Task task){
      this.tasks.add(task);
   }

   public void runTasks(){
      // looping to run all tasks
      for(Task task : tasks){
         task.doTask();
      }
   }

}

// tester class
public class Tester{
   public static void main(String[] args){

   // creating 2 dummy tasks
   Task t1 = new Task("show-files","ls -ls");
   Task t2 = new Task("show-proc","ps -ef");

   // creating 2 summy machines
   Machine m1 = new Machine(1, 8, 500);
   Machine m2 = new Machine(2, 16, 1000);

   // adding tasks to machines
   m1.addTask(t1);
   m2.addTask(t1);
   m2.addTask(t2);

   // run tasks on target machines
   m1.runTasks();
   m2.runTasks();
  }
}
```

Comment: is there a way to get the tasks that is running in a given time?

Comment: This is not the actual requirement